# Error in cypress object model : Cannot find module '../ObjectModel/LoginPage'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, cypress, object-model

I tried to write object model in vscode, to create an object.

This is login2 :

```js
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
          
import LoginPage from "../../integration/ObjectModel/LoginPage"

describe('home page', () => {
    it('loginPage', function () {
        const lp = new LoginPage()
    })
})
```

This is object page :

```js
class LoginPage {
    visit(){
        cy.visit('https://facebook.com');
    }

    fillEmail(value){
        const feild = cy.get('#email')
        feild.clear()
        feild.type(value)
        return this
    }
    
    fillPassword(value){
        const feild = cy.get('#pass')
        feild.clear()
        feild.type(value)
        return this
    }
    
    submit(){
        const button = cy.get('#u_0_b')
        button.click()
    }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

This is the path of files:
[image]
and this the error
[image]

How I can solve it?
I tried to change the path as I read, also it does not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the file `login2.js` is in the same directory as ObjectModel. Thus you only need to import file like this:

```js
import LoginPage from "./ObjectModel/LoginPage"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the import/export, which is newer/modern version to `module.exports` and it works only when you install babel and setup the babel configuration to transform the modules in order to work with `import/export`. Please try to replace `export default LoginPage` with `module.exports = new LoginPage();` in the page class.

```
const LoginPage = require("../../integration/ObjectModel/LoginPage")
```

And in your it/test, you don't need to say `const lp = new LoginPage()` as you are importing the page on top with `require`

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved by changing the path to

```
    import LoginPage from "./ObjectModel/LoginPage"
```